# Is the new Date better than the old Date?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a CalendarTimeUTC Dimension table in our Data Warehouse that looks like this:

[image]

The PK in the table is the CalendarTimeUTCId (clustered). This used to be a Int field. All fact tables have CalendarId in them (some of these are multi-billion row partitioned tables).

We want to go from putting a DATE value to DATE+HOUR value in this field.

Sample data (Old and New):

[image]

Now with the advent of SQL 2008, and the shiny new implementation of DATETIME, is there a reason to switch the dimension's ID column from INT to DATETIME?

How will it affect the Index Size in the fact tables? More importantly, how will it affect performance?

Comment: I wouldn't put hours in with date field - 24 times more records in your calendar dimension....

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this is connected to the `date` type. Previously (before SQL Server 2008, I understand) your calendar table contained only dates, but the values were of `datetime` type, because there was no `date` type in SQL Server then. Now you are planning to add the time portion, and again you'll have to use `datetime`. So what do you mean by implicating `date`?

Comment: @Andriy M: Mistype on my part - I mean `DATETIME`.

Comment: Raj, why are you doing this in the first place? Sql Server 2005 has a DateTime data type. What part of the 2008 version is shiny and new? Why are you creating an id that looks like a date? Why are you storing a date that look like the ID? Are there more fields in your Calendar Dimension table that you are not showing?

Answer (score 1):

**Datetime** datatype takes up 8 bytes.  **Int** datatype takes only 4 bytes.  If you *wanted* to convert to a **date** datatype (because you needed to make use of date manipulation functions, for example), I'd suggest using **smalldatetime** which only takes 4 bytes.

As far as indexes and performance: because the indexes would be on the same physical size of data, I don't believe you'd see a performance hit nor an increase in the size of the indexes.